# how to link a html code in another html document

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, game-development

I am making a game and I want to pubish on a platform in which parent site will communicate with the game, so I can give the whole code to the site. But when I will have to update then it will make problem to me, so I thought to link html game in another a html file.

**NOTE:- Like we link stylesheet and script in html then these codes are visible to the main page's source code like that the html code should be linked**.

Hope, anybody can help me

i used this code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.get("index.html", function(data) {

            $("#ht-content").html(data);

        });

    });
```

This code was working also but there was a problem that because of this my game doesn't work properly. So I need another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So there is very little info to work with but I can think of an approach.

So here is an example HTML file that will be published on the platform:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My awesome game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="https://yourwebsite.com/myawesomegame.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

We will use an `iframe` tag and link it to the game HTML file where you have control, like your website or Vercel, Netlify, and GitHub pages hosting.

Now without much info, it's hard to say if the host site will be able to interact with iframe or not or it's in your control to code it in a way to be able to interact with the host site.

---

**`iframe` Documentation**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe